# beyond compare - how to ignore punctuation marks

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

It's as simple as the title states.
I have 2 docx files I need to compare, and I want to see all the differences BUT punctuation marks (commas, periods, etc.), as there are too many of them and I'm not going to take these anyway.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the two docx files in Beyond Compare.
2. Click the **Rules** toolbar button (referee icon).
3. Go to the **Importance** tab.
4. Under **Unimportant Text**, click **+**.
5. **Text to find:** ,
6. Click OK until you're back to the main window.

Repeat for each additional punctuation type.

If **View > Ignore Unimportant Differences** is on, unimportant differences will show as a match, if it is off they will show in blue.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot!